# Django Invalid filter: 'truncatechars_html'

Tags: css, django

I am trying to display content that has HTML tagS in it and also wants to truncate it if the character is more than 1000 but it is affecting my CSS layout if article is truncated at a tag that is opened and not closed before the truncation point.

**Code:**

```
{% if article.content_length > 1000 %}
    <p>
        {{article.content|truncatechars_html:1000|safe|linebreaks}}
    </p>
    <a href="#">See more...</a>
{% else %}
    <p>
        {{article.content|safe|linebreaks}}
    </p>
{% endif %}
```

Though `{{article.content|truncatechars:1000|safe|linebreaks}}` works fine but when I change it to `{{article.content|truncatechars_html:1000|safe|linebreaks}}` I get the error below:

**TemplateSyntaxError at /mysite/article/mysite/**

**Invalid filter: 'truncatechars_html'**.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using Django 1.7 or later. The `truncatechars_html` filter is not available in earlier versions.